# Как «развязать» взаимосвязанные поля в моделях Backbone?

Tags: javascript, mvc, backbone.js

У меня компонент даты в котором можно выбирать временной период и модель в которой есть три поля:

- startDate - начало периода
- endDate - конец периода
- period - какое-то число равное количесту дней. Можно выбирать день, неделю и т.д. и тогда его значение будет равно 1, 7 и т.д. соответсвенно

Для каждого поля модели есть соответсвующий элемент интерфейса.
Алгоритм работы следующий:

1. Я изменил period:

   - endDate - остается неизменным
   - startDate - вычисляется как endDate - period
   - контрол, который отображает значение поля period, должен отображать сооветсвующий период
   - контролы, которые отображают значения полей endDate и startDate, так же обновляются
2. Я изменил startDate:

   - period - сбросился, поскольку более не равен какому-то предустановленному значению
   - контрол который отображает значение поля period должен "сброситься"

И вот тут самое интересное. Когдя я обновляю, например, поле period то должны обновиться и поля endDate и startDate, а их обновление сразу ведет к обновлению поля period в пустое значение, что, конечно, не верно.
И вопрос в том как это побороть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас противоречие в условии задачи

> Я изменил period: endDate - остается неизменным

далее

> я обновляю, например, поле period то должны обновиться и поля endDate и startDate

Обратите внимание на документацию по методу **set** у модели - http://backbonejs.ru/#Model-set
Установка нового значения аттрибута модели может быть выполнена с параметром:

```
{ silent : true }
```

С помощью него можно обойти нежелательные "цепные реакции" обновления модели и заглушить многочисленные вызовы события "**change**" на ней:

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults : {
    start : 10,
    period : 7
  },
  initialize : function () {
    this.on('change', this.calc);
    this.set('end', this.get('start') + this.get('period'), { silent : true });
  },
  calc : function () {
    var silent = { silent : true };

    if (this.changed.start) {
      this.set('period', this.get('end') - this.get('start'), silent);
    }

    if (this.get('period')) {
      this.set('start', this.get('end') - this.get('period'), silent);
    }
    this.trigger('updated');
    console.log('update triggered');
  },
});
```

Полный пример тут: http://jsbin.com/taxahenige/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Смысл в том, чтобы модель обновляла свои данные "тихо" и, после завершения всей логики, вызывала на себе событие обновления, которое слушает представление:

```
this.listenTo(this.model, 'updated', this.render, this);
```