# Backbone: замыкание между моделью и интерфейсом

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js

Допустим у меня 2 input'а через 2 View связаны с общей моделью. Если меняется значение в поле #1 то оно записывает в модель и отрисовывается во поле #2.
Но поле #1 также регистрирует изменение модели и устанавливает такое же значение, которое там и так уже есть.
Как избежать ненужной отрисовки для View #1?
В моём примере можно попробовать сравнивать текущее значение поля и модели, но если View состоит из множества полей такое не прокатит.

Comment: А что вы используете для связи инпута с моделью? Какие-то библиотеки для биндинга или свою реализацию основанную на стандартных средствах Backbone т.e. через события View?

Comment: Средствами Backbone, через события View: `'change input' : function(){}`

Comment: @powrtoch посмотрите вот этот вопрос http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/424687/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%85-backbone/428925 в нём, как мне кажется, можно найти ответ

Answer (score 1):

Проще всего повесить два разных обработчика на первый и второй input. Чтобы изменение первого input вызывали первый обработчик и отрисовывали 2ой input. Аналогично для второго.